# Java: Apache Regression gives me absolutly wrong regression parameters

Tags: java, regression, apache-commons-math

I wanted to get regression parameters by using Apache's Commons.Math3 library and the OLSMultipleLinearRegression.
The regression should be polynomial with a power of 2.
It worked fine with test data but when I use this experimental data the methode gives me an absolutely wrong regression.

```
public static void poly (){
OLSMultipleLinearRegression quadRegression = new OLSMultipleLinearRegression();

double [] y = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,
               26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,
               51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59};

double [][] x = {{1.00,1.00},{1.00,1.00},{1.00,1.00},{1.00,1.00},{1.00,1.00},{1.00,1.00},{1.00,1.00},{1.00,1.00},{1.00,1.00},{0.95,0.90},{0.96,0.91},{0.96,0.92},{0.96,0.92},{0.96,0.92},{0.92,0.84},{0.92,0.85},
{0.92,0.86},{0.93,0.86},{0.93,0.87},{0.89,0.80},{0.90,0.81},{0.90,0.81},{0.90,0.82},{0.89,0.80},{0.90,0.81},{0.90,0.82},{0.91,0.82},{0.91,0.83},{0.90,0.80},{0.90,0.80},{0.90,0.81},{0.91,0.82},
{0.89,0.79},{0.89,0.80},{0.90,0.80},{0.90,0.81},{0.88,0.77},{0.88,0.77},{0.88,0.78},{0.88,0.78},{0.86,0.73},{0.86,0.74},{0.86,0.74},{0.86,0.74},{0.84,0.71},{0.85,0.72},{0.85,0.72},{0.85,0.73},
{0.84,0.71},{0.84,0.71},{0.84,0.71},{0.84,0.71},{0.83,0.69},{0.83,0.69},{0.83,0.69},{0.82,0.68},{0.82,0.68},{0.82,0.68},{0.82,0.68}};

quadRegression.newSampleData(y, x);
quadRegression.setNoIntercept(false);

double [] results = quadRegression.estimateRegressionParameters();}
```

For this input data I get the equation y=117.54x²-504.83x+389.088 which would result in a y-value of 379.760.85 for x=59 - way beyond my input value.
So I either handled the class absolutly wrong or I got stuck in a mathematical pitfall.

If someone please could explain me what I did wrong or misinterpreted - this problem drives me insane.

Comment: Are you sure you mean 59 as x value? That value is way outside the x values that you used to estimate that model.